# How to send multiple unique push notifications with AWS Pinpoint in one call?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, push-notification, aws-pinpoint

I have figured out how to send one basic message to a list of users with `sendUsersMessages`. However, I can't figure out how to customize the message for each user with substitutions. Also, should I use `sendMessages` or `sendUsersMessages` if I am sending unique messages for each user?

The documentation is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Pinpoint.html), but is hard to understand. All the examples found online seem to just send one push notification.

How can I convert the following to sending different users customized push notifications?

```
 const gcmRawContent = JSON.stringify({
    data: {
      title,
      message: pushText,
      experienceId,
      channelId,
      body,
    },
  });

  const messageConfiguration = {
    MessageConfiguration: {
      GCMMessage: {
        RawContent: gcmRawContent,
      },
    },
  };

  const sendMessagesParams = {
    ApplicationId,
    SendUsersMessageRequest: {
      Users: { 'userId1': {}, 'userId2': {} },
      ...messageConfiguration,
    },
  };
  const pinpoint = new AWS.Pinpoint();
  await pinpoint.sendUsersMessages(batchSendMessagesParams).promise();
```

Comment: Are you looking for a completely different message for all the users, or for example you want to insert their first name dynamically somewhere within the notification?

Comment: A completely different message. Although could that just be simplified to having dynamic properties (title, message...)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Amazon Pinpoint.

Based on the documentation you shared this should be possible by setting the `Substitutions` value on the user object.

eg.

```
Users: {
    'userId1': {
        Substitutions: {
            'mysub': ['some value']
        }
    },
    'userId2': { 
        Substitutions: {
            'mysub': ['some other value']
        }
    }
}
```